# HBase REST/Stargate PUT

Tags: hbase, stargate

Running HBase 1.1.0.1 standalone, accessing Stargate API and was able to create table with two columns 'c' & 'd'. I'm currently trying to insert into one column using the following curl command. It returns 400 Bad Request without any explanation in the logs.

I've tried both http://localhost:8080/table1/row1 & http://localhost:8080/table1/row1/c

Formatted JSON from the comments section on issue [HBase](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-9435?focusedCommentId=13778282&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13778282)

curl -v -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" 'http://localhost:8080/table1/row1' --data '{"Row":[{"key":"cm93MQ==", "Cell":[{"column":"Yw==", "$":"dmFsdWU="}]}]}'

Can somebody help with what I'm missing with the above request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your Json, you have mentioned only the column family ('c') not the qualifier..

table1 is the table name.. row1 is the row key.. c is the column family.. Whats the column name? 
Encode c:columnname using base64 and then use that in the column field in the json.. 
Hope this helps!